# How can I find out what nameservers have been assigned to my DNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I have a domain with Amazon but when I try to access it I get a message saying:

```
DNS Lookup for "www.abc.com" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

Is there a way that I can check what nameservers are assigned for that DNS?

Comment: Have you tried looking up just the domain name "abc.com" without the "www"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find http://mxtoolbox.com a useful website for this sort of thing.

Its meant for checking mX records, but after you do that there are DNS checks and other useful domain related lookups you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what name servers Amazon has assigned for serving requests for your domain then log into the AWS console, navigate to the `Route53` settings, click on `Hosted Zones`, then click on the name of your domain. At the top of your list of records for your domain you will see an NS record.  That record lists all the DNS servers for your domain.